# Setting Config Variables Permanently

Tags: laravel-5

I was trying to save my configration variables permanently. For example app.debug i want to change dynamically in my control panel and save it permanently.

I tried lot of packages but not supporting laravel 5.2 or i cant:

- https://github.com/Phil-F/Setting/
- https://github.com/daftspunk/laravel-config-writer
- https://github.com/anlutro/laravel-settings

When I try to overwrite, its going to more big problem because some variables need to get in to environment. How can i do this?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

I coded a new package for Laravel 5.x and i can make permanently config variable with this code below

```
Permacon::set("config", "locale", "tr");
```

Permacon Package => https://github.com/furkankadioglu/Permacon